# How do I adjust the resolution on an Intel gma x3100?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, resolution

I'm with fresh install of 12.04, having gma x3100 as a video card. The problem is I own 19" monitor with native resolution of 1280x1024 but can't force screen resolution on more then 1024x768

```
~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```

I been digging up some info for the past 2 days, yet haven't found any solution. Even tried using gdm instead of lightdm.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of my determination to keep using my motherboard's build in video card, I finally managed to find out how to fix this issue with 12.04 and 12.10.

I have an 9800GT video card which i'm not using. I set it up, booted and the resolution was 1280x1024, which was exactly what i wanted. Checking the drivers let me know that some generic nvidia driver was used. I shutted down the machine, pluged out the video card and booted again. Voilla, ubuntu was wise enough to keep the resolution at 1280x1024.

Also I found out that this issue with gma x3100 is starting with 11.04 till the most recent one. So.. if you have the same problem and you can borrow a video card for simple plug in/out, you will continue using your gma happily.